# Update Duplicate column values based on Count in MySQl

Tags: mysql

I Have a Table like this

```
Employeeid  Name   CompanyID
1           Achal      1
2           Anil       1
3           Anil       1
4           Sachi      2
5           Anil       2
6           Sachi      1
7           Sachi      2
```

I want to update the names of the employee if multiple employees are there in a same company

My resultant table should be like this

```
Employeeid  Name   CompanyID
1           Achal      1
2           Anil(1)    1
3           Anil(2)    1
4           Sachi(1)   2
5           Anil       2
6           Sachi      1
7           Sachi(2)   2
```

My query is something like this

```
Update tblemplayee emp 
join 
(
  select sname,count(*) 
  from tblemployee 
  group by sname,companyid
) innertable 
  on innertable.employeeid=emp.employeeid 
set sname = concat(sname,'(', ,')') .
```

How can i change my query to get the result.

Comment: Why do you want to UPDATE the data in the table to do this?  What happens when you get more `Anil` values for companyid =1?  You'll have to update it each time, please reconsider doing this.  If you need to return the count, then do it in a select not an update.

Comment: The new entries will be managed by the code. Since we have added a new column to the table, to mako know that many en user know that many entries are there we have to do this. Later the user will update the values. The above table is just a example ..

Answer (score 1):

If you need to execute your query only once, you could use this query:

```
UPDATE
  employees INNER JOIN (
    SELECT e1.Employeeid, COUNT(e2.Employeeid) n
    FROM
      employees e1 INNER JOIN employees e2
      ON e1.Name=e2.Name
         AND e1.CompanyID=e2.CompanyID
         AND e1.Employeeid>=e2.Employeeid
      INNER JOIN (SELECT Name, CompanyID
                  FROM employees
                  GROUP BY Name, CompanyID
                  HAVING COUNT(*)>1) dup
      ON e1.Name=dup.Name AND e1.CompanyID=dup.CompanyID
    GROUP BY
      e1.Employeeid, e1.Name) counts
  ON employees.Employeeid = counts.Employeeid
SET
  Name = CONCAT(Name, '(', counts.n, ')');
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1a32a/1).